# How does a motif from Motifinvesting work?

Tags: stocks, investing, etf

I wondering if anyone here have experience with buying motifs that motifinvesting offers. They are like customization etfs up to 30 different stocks. The minimum requirement to buy a motif is $250.

What happens when I buy a motif that has consist of stocks that has a value larger than $250. Would motifinvesting buy a fraction of the share (which I don't think is possible) or would they buy the whole share and allocate a portion of it to me?

Comment: I think this Q&A combination are being downvoted because people see it as spam/astroturfing. I can see why it gives that impression, but I don't think it is actually the case here.

Comment: I promise I am not affiliate with them in anyway. I had no idea what fraction sharing investing was until I did some googling. I've been searching for a way to invest in Amazon but the price was way too high for me to even buy a share.

Comment: Motif Investing closed in May 2020.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did a little digging and they do fractional share investing. Orders can be as small as 0.01 of the share.

Source: https://www.motifinvesting.com/blog/the-benefits-fractional-shares-for-investors